# Understanding a proof of the covariance matrix of a random process in SDE

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Considering the following SDE with multiplicative as well as additive stochastic uncertainty,
$$
\dot{x}=A x+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell} B_{\ell} x \xi_{\ell}+H \eta
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, H \in \mathbb{R}^n$; for $\ell=1, \cdots, m$,
$\xi_{\ell}=\frac{d \Delta_{\ell}}{\iota}, \eta=\frac{d \zeta}{u}$ with $\Delta_1, \cdots , \Delta_m$ and $\zeta$ being the standard independent Wiener process.

How to prove the following Lemma:

Let the covariance matrix, $\bar{Q}(t)=E\left[x(t) x(t)^{\top} \mid \psi\right]:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x x^{\top} \psi(x, t) d x$, and $\bar{Q}(0):=\bar{Q}_0<$ $\infty$, then $\bar{Q}(t)$ satisfies the following matrix differential equation (MDE)

$$
\dot{\bar{Q}}=\bar{Q} A^{\top}+A \bar{Q}+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2 B_{\ell} \bar{Q} B_{\ell}^{\top}+H H^{\top}
$$

Here is the detailed proof:

Taking the time derivative on both sides and after simplification, we obtain [1, Theorem 11.9.1]
$$
\frac{d E[V \mid \psi]}{d t}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j=1}^n\left[\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2\left(b_{\ell}^i x\right)\left(b_{\ell}^j x\right)+h_i h_j\right] \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(a_i x\right) \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}\right\} \psi(x, t) d x=E[\mathcal{L} V \mid \psi] .
$$

where the term $\mathcal{L} V$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{L} V=x^{\top}\left(A^{\top} P+P A+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2 B_{\ell}^{\top} P B_{\ell}\right) x+H^{\top} P H .
$$

The time derivative of $E[V \mid \psi]$ is obtained by doing integration by parts where we make use of Remark 4 .
In particular, we make use of the fact that the products, $\psi V, \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_i} V, \psi \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}$ vanish exponentially as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$ and hence, the higher order moments become zero. By substituting $\mathcal{L} V$ in the above euqation, and using the linearity of trace, expectation and commutativity inside trace, we obtain,
$$
d\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(E\left[x x^{\top} \mid \psi\right] P\right)\right) / d t=\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(A^{\top} P+P A+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2 B_{\ell}^{\top} P B_{\ell}\right) E\left[x x^{\top} \mid \psi\right]+H H^{\top} P\right) .
$$

By definition of expectation, $E\left[x x^{\top} \mid \psi\right]=\bar{Q}$, we have,
$$
\operatorname{tr}(\dot{\bar{Q}} P)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\bar{Q} A^{\top}+A \bar{Q}+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2 B_{\ell} \bar{Q} B_{\ell}^{\top}+H H^{\top}\right) P\right) .
$$

This can be rewritten in terms of an inner product as
$$
\left\langle\dot{\bar{Q}}-\left(\bar{Q} A^{\top}+A \bar{Q}+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2 B_{\ell} \bar{Q} B_{\ell}^{\top}+H H^{\top}\right), P\right\rangle=0
$$

since $P>0$, $\dot{\bar{Q}}=\bar{Q} A^{\top}+A \bar{Q}+\sum_{\ell=1}^m \sigma_{\ell}^2 B_{\ell} \bar{Q} B_{\ell}^{\top}+H H^{\top}$

[1] A. Lasota and M. C. Mackey, Chaos, Fractals, and Noise: Stochastic Aspects of Dynamics. New York: Springer-Verlag, 1994

Since I have no access to the context of ref [1], I'm just confused of the above derivation of $\frac{d E[V \mid \psi]}{d t}$, could someone offer me a more detailed calculation, thanks.

Comment: could you tell me what book you are reading because I recently read the same result  ( it didn't say it was lemma but rather just wrote it ) and was also wondering where the first two terms of $Q$ dot came from also. So I'm just curious what the text is ?  Thanks.

Comment: The corresponding article is $S. Pushpak, A. Diwadkar, and U. Vaidya, “Mean square stability analysis and synthesis of stochastic continuous-time linear networked systems,” arXiv preprint, 2016. [Online]. Available: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02857.pdf". If you have any further understanding of this proof, please share it with me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks yuqi. It looks like you gave more details, so let me go through those and see if I can understand them first. The references and details are appreciated. I'll get back to you but I'm not confident that I can help.

Comment: yuqi: I can't get free access to the text you referenced but I found a document at the link below. I haven't gone over it carefully but in pages in the 40's, there is a claim that ITO's formula is used to derive a similar equation. I can't look at it really carefully now but maybe it will be helpful to you. When I have a chance, I'll look at it more closely. Also, if I find more anything more useful, I'll let you know.  Thanks for interesting question. https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/dynamic-systems-n-control/idsc-dam/Lectures/Stochastic-Systems/SDE.pdf

Comment: yuqi: The infintesimal generator equation on page 22 of this looks quite similar to what is inside the integral of $d(E(V| \psi)/dt$ in the paper you reference. https://www.math.drexel.edu/~song/Gene%20Golub%20Summer%20School/Nualart/Lecture-3.pdf  Unfortunately, the question still remains: How is it derived ?

Comment: yuqi: Here's a link that is relevant ( I just ordered the book from amazon ). I'm just putting all the relevant things here so that I can come back to them later when time makes that possible. Hopefully they are helpful to you in the mean time. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645405/is-there-a-closed-expression-for-a-lti-sde-covariance-matrix